# Getting the attributes of HTML link clicked

Tags: c++, windows, webbrowser-control, visual-c++

I'm starting to use MS Visual C++ 2010 express. I've had the following problem, I use a webBrowser control to view html documents and need to get the attributes (could it be just one) of clicked link, is it possible? and if it is then how to do this?

Thanks for all replies and sorry for my bad english ;p

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the WebBrowserControl from MSHTML (Trident), you should be able to retrieve the clicked URL in the function OnBeforeNavigate2() or in the Invoke() of your DWebBrowserEvents2 on reception of  DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2.

(The URL is the second parameter).

To have more details and explanations. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/aa768280%28en-us,VS.85%29.aspx)